# bPopup won't postback

Tags: jquery, postback, bpopup

I have bPopup that opens a div with a textbox and a Send button.

However when I click on the send button nothing happens.  The click does not raise a postback event.  Does anyone know why?

Comment: Spent hours on the problem, ten minutes after posting this question I worked it out :-(

For asp.net us the appendTo option  $('#PopUpDiv').bPopup({ appendTo: 'form' });

Answer (score 1):

here's your answer in case you are still in need...

This line should be in your jQuery area:  appendTo: 'form'

It's documented on the bPopup page, but it's not overly obvious.

Go to this page:  [bPopup documentation](http://dinbror.dk/blog/bpopup/comment-page-9/#Options)

And search for "ASP.NET".

Hope this helps!  I had the same issue and spent 3 hours on it before stumbling across this fix.